# Pass same value on all parameters?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, sqlcommand

Is it possible to pass value for all the parameter of `SqlCommand` without hardcoding?

Instead of this:

```
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", "sameValue");
mySqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", "sameValue");
mySqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", "sameValue");
...
```

I want some like this:

```
foreach (SqlParameter parameter in mySqlCommand1.Parameters)
{
    parameter.Value = someValue;  
}
```

But I get an error:

> Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Comment: Obviously you answered your own question...the code sample shows you can...

Comment: But it did not work on me. Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied.

Comment: Then you need to elaborate a little bit on what didn't work, what errors you got, where someValue is coming from etc...I can guess what your real question....

Comment: How does your stored proc looks like? Have you already filled Parameters?

Comment: Are you looking for [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - **if** you **add** the parameters to the `.Parameters` collection first:

```
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.Int);
mySqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
...
```

Then you can iterate over them and assign values:

```
foreach (SqlParameter parameter in mySqlCommand1.Parameters)
{
    parameter.Value = someValue;  
}
```

If you didn't add those parameters to the `.Parameters` collection, then there's nothing to **iterate over** and assign values to .....

**Update:** if you want to avoid `@Parameter1`, use something like this:

```
foreach (SqlParameter parameter in mySqlCommand1.Parameters)
{
    if(parameter.ParameterName != "@Parameter1") 
    { 
        parameter.Value = someValue;  
    }
}
```

Comment: could i have this?  foreach (SqlParameter parameter in mySqlCommand1.Parameters != @Parameter1)

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski: what is that code supposed to do???

Comment: add that sameValue to all parameters except to @Parameter1

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski: inside the `foreach`, you could use `if(parameter.ParameterName != "@Parameter1") { .... }`

Answer (score 0):

That bears the question - does the values actually vary?

- If they don't, then maybe you can change your stored procedure to accept just one parameter, and then propagate it internally.
- If it does, then you may change your procedure in order to make it accept optional parameters, like this example:

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcName
      @Parameter1 VARCHAR (100) = '1',
      @Parameter2 VARCHAR (100) = 'StringValue',
      @Parameter3 VARCHAR (100) = NULL
  AS [...]
  ```

If you implement optional parameters you don't need to mention any further values - defaults can be assumed. That way, your client code can be streamlined.

Comment: Opitonal parameter will have default value if the parameter is not set?

Comment: That's exactly it. According to MSDN (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx ), quote: 'You can create a stored procedure with optional parameters by specifying a default value for optional parameters. When the stored procedure is executed, the default value is used if no other value has been specified.'